# Criar novo step em um JOB

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-azure

Estou tentando criar um novo "step" para um job pelo Azure Data Studio, mas ele não está disponibilizando o botão "OK" para confirmar a criação.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AU4V.png)

Comment: @novic obrigado pela edição, mas foi necessário reverte-la https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8764/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento? o que foi!

Comment: @novic o ideal é que edições devem viabilizar a reabertura das perguntas. Obrigado por compreender.

Comment: Não compreendi @GuilhermeNascimento, eu coloquei a imagem para que eu possa ver o que o usuário quis dizer com a pergunta, e outra, o sistema é bulgado e não desabilita o botão! a culpa é do sistema, se ele não impede quem dirá nós!

Comment: Está tudo no link indicado acima, ajustes feitos pela empresa propositalmente para que os usuários com menos de 10 pontos tenham as imagens exibidas como link, no entanto se for de fato uma imagem e edição que possa viabilizar a reabertura, então estaria 'ok' edita-la, não é o caso ainda. Duvidas sobre o funcionamento do site devem seguir no META.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento isso é um falha do sistema, então, reclame você no meta. Inclusive o link você lê a resposta acima que vai entender o que eu estou falando, o sistema não bloqueia nada só aciona um regra que pode ser burlada por outros usuários, qualquer problema deve seguir no META com o seu posicionamento.

Comment: @novic sim, estamos cientes disso, é uma limitação, eu não disse em momento algum que era um bloqueio. Novamente, como já disse, está no META, está orientado e infelizmente é o que tem de possível para tentar melhorar a situação de mau uso das imagens. Focando na parte que importa, a edição, elas são boas se viabilizarem a reabertura, se não for o caso evite-as. Se tiver questionamentos faça o que disse no começo, leia o link do META e questione lá, é o local correto. Obrigado por compreender.